# Issues regrading using a message queue service bus in .NET

Tags: c#, architecture, servicebus, masstransit

I would like to hear your opinions about a subject that bothers me in the last few days..

In our project we are using MassTransit servic bus. we create a
singleton instance of IServiceBus (interface of MassTransit) using IoC container, and all the classes that need this IServiceBus get it in the constructor.
This caused that a lot of classes in our project gets the IServiceBus as a constructor parameter, which makes them coupled with the MassTransit service bus, and actually to the concept of notification using a message queue.

I think that it is a bad example of coupling.

By passing the IServiceBus to various classes, we are defining the way that this class should send notifications to out side listeners, and forcing the way to be a service bus oriented way.

I think that the classic way of .NET is better - the class should define an event in its interface with a .NET event handler, and any observer that would like to use this event handler should subscribe to it.

What we earn in that way is that we are not committed to an implementation of a class with a service bus. That way, the service bus can become an observer for that class event handler, and when that event occurs, it raises logic that sends some message to the service bus queue.

This also raises a big question..

When and why should we use service bus in a project, given that the project runs on a single process?

If the projects consists of several processes I can see the advantages because it is easier to pass strong typed messages using a message queue, but I cant understand the benefits when it is in one process scope.
If I want classes to inform notifications to observers, consumers etc, I would raise an event from within the class, and create a single or closed group of dispatcher classes that will subscribe to all these events in my project, that way I can handle the logic of the message transportation. Also,in that way the logic of adding an observer will be centered at one place in the project.

I will be glad to hear your thoughts on the subject..

Guy

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a great SO question. It's likely to be closed. Regardless to your questions, the surface area of `IServiceBus` is pretty small. You easily replace it if you needed. Consumers are more coupled if you implement the `Consumes.*` interfaces. But you can just register consumers as delegates, then it doesn't matter. The end result should be that the overall coupling of your system is less.

Lastly, you use a service bus so you don't need to worry about message transportation or delivery. While there is sometimes inner-process communication isn't really a problem - at it's easy to break apart in the future.